# JSON manipulation in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I need to edit some data in a JSON file, and I'm looking to do so in PHP.  My JSON file looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "field1":"data1-1",
        "field2":"data1-2"
    },
    {
        "field1":"data2-1",
        "field2":"data2-2"
    }
]
```

What I've done so far is `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents(foo.json))` but I have no idea how to navigate this array.  If for example I want to find the data from the first field of the second object, what's the PHP syntax to do so?  Also, are there other ways I should know about for parsing JSON data into a PHP friendly format?

Comment: If you do `json_decode(file_get_contents(foo.json), true)` you get an assoc array that is generally easier to work with than objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This JSON contains 2 arrays with 2 objects each, you can access like this:

```
$arr = json_decode(file_get_contents(foo.json));
// first array
echo $arr[0]->field1;
echo $arr[0]->field2;
// second array
echo $arr[1]->field1;
echo $arr[1]->field2;
```

if you convert this to an array and avoid objects you can then access like this:

```
$arr = json_decode(file_get_contents(foo.json), true);
// first array
echo $arr[0]['field1'];
echo $arr[0]['field2'];
// second array
echo $arr[1]['field1'];
echo $arr[1]['field2'];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents(foo.json)); 
foreach($data as $k => &$obj) {

    $obj->field1 = 'new-data1-1';
    $obj->field2 = 'new-data1-2';

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use this code to navigate through your json format. This code is dynamic and can navigate for any number of objects you have in your result.

```
<?php
$json ='[
    {
        "field1":"data1-1",
        "field2":"data1-2"
    },
    {
        "field1":"data2-1",
        "field2":"data2-2"
    }
]';

if($encoded=json_decode($json,true))
{
    echo 'encoded';

    // loop through the json values
    foreach($encoded as $key=>$value)
    {
        echo'<br>object index: '.$key.'<br>';
        foreach($value as $bKey=>$bValue)
        {
            echo '<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$bValue.' = '.$bValue;
        }

    }
    // get a perticular item
    echo '<br>object[0][field1]: '.$encoded[0]['field1'];

}
else
{
    echo'error on syntax';


}
?>
```

Which will have following output

```
encoded
object index: 0

  data1-1 = data1-1
  data1-2 = data1-2
object index: 1

  data2-1 = data2-1
  data2-2 = data2-2
object[0][field1]: data1-1
```